# How to get xml text as simple text

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I use go-xmldom for parsing xml docments.

```
doc, _ := xmldom.ParseXML(tmpStr)
root := doc.Root
someNode := root.getChild("someChild")
// someNode.Text is empty
// someNode.Xml() is not correct data without {{range}} operator
```

```
<root>
   <someChild>
      {{range $item := .list}}
        <item>{{$item}}</item>
      {{end}}
   </someChild>
<root>
```

someNode - it is node with golang template and I need to get it as simple text. 
But **someNode.Text = ""** and **someNode.Children** - it is not correct data, 
because there are operators like **{{range ...}}**, **{{if...}}** and so on.
How can I get some tag as simple text?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/subchen/go-xmldom/blob/master/node.go#L200)?

Comment: someChild.XML() returns xml without {{range}} operator

Comment: You said you want plain XML _text_ of your node, and then you say something about `range`. I fail to connect these two points. I mean, if you want the XML test of `someChild`, then call `XML()` on it and be done with it, no?

Comment: I need something like `xml:",innerxml"` for go-xmldom